# I just got 190 reputation points robbed! Could someone explain to me why?

Tags: discussion, reputation, serial-voting, voting-correction

On **August 16th**, a user that I had helped several times in a row,  decided by himself to upvote all my answers, granting me above **200 reputation points** in a matter of minutes. **I guess** (because I don't know him), that it was some kind of action to show gratitude from his part. The next day (**August 17th**) I got a message from several moderators asking me about this suspicious activity. I explained to them the same I just said. And they decided to subtract me **210 reputation points** (as you can see in the picture I'm including in this post). I didn't complain because I thought it was fair, and besides, I don't want to have any problems with this community.

Since that experience, all the reputation points I have earned were mainly by answering questions and by editing posts. But [today I just got **190 reputation points** subtracted](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7471180/sagnalrac?tab=reputation) without any kind of explanation.

[image]

You can check my recent activity from August 17th to yesterday if you want. I don't have anything to hide.

Are you telling me that all this time I've just answered the same user questions but he/she created  different accounts? Oh, come on!

So, as the title of my post says, could someone explain to me what just happened?

**UPDATE:**

It seems that Stack Exchange Staff **returned me 60 reputation points** (the other 10 were because a recent upvote in one of my answers), because part of the 190 points they subtracted me, were because they also reverted my 4 accepted answers to the the "grateful user" questions (they also reverted the "grateful user" upvotes to my answers from those questions, equivalent to **40 rep pts.**, although they were his/her only valid upvotes. LOL). See? I told you something was wrong.
[image]

Thank you very much to whoever helped me with this really unfair situation.

Comment: Your reputation activity page states that this was a "voting correction" with a link to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed), but doesn't tell us exactly what was corrected, but something was off. Hopefully, a moderator will have the ability to identify this and come to this question and clarify the issue for you. Likely you received more serial (or otherwise not earned) up-votes.

Comment: aren't you trying to cheat the system by any chance? Such voting corrected are very accurate and they never remove legit upvotes, only clear and suspicious ones.

Comment: @TemaniAfif: if the moderators suspected this, they would likely have zeroed out the OP's account, no?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels no. They will either remove the votes (like this case) and probably send a warning (or not) and in some cases they may give the user a ban. I don't know exactly the logic but based on all the voting fraud I flagged, in most of the cases it's only a voting corrected (a recent example with more than 500: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6195644/ehsan?tab=reputation and no ban)

Comment: @TemaniAfif That does seem like the logical assumption, but most users stop after one warning. I know I did ;). And they wouldn't raise a meta post asking why if they know why it happened.

Comment: @10Rep *they wouldn't raise a meta post asking why if they know why it happened* --> maybe they don't know that the system can catch such behavior thinking that another account slowly upvoting him is ok. A moderator will soon give us more detail (if the OP didn't delete this question before that)

Comment: If they do delete the Q, we can always vote to undelete it, because "inquiring minds want to know" :D

Comment: @TemaniAfif True, true. I got punished rightly for sock puppeting, and I remember thinking, wow, they got all the test cases!

Comment: Ok, thanks for your comments but, could someone point where is the supposed fraudulent/suspicious activity? That was the reason for why I included a picture with my recent activity. Only questions answered and few edited posts

Comment: @TemaniAfif: Did you check my recent activity at least? I can't control other user actions, and I can't see who are upvoting my answers

Comment: @Sagnalrac Have you been sock-puppeting? Voting on your questions with a seperate account?

Comment: @10Rep: No, never! Even in the past occasion I wasn't, like I explained in my post. That was the main reason for why I didn't complaint that day, but I can't also control other users actions. Can mods check who did an upvote? All this time I had the idea it was the OP of every question I had answered who upvoted my answer.

Comment: Maybe someone voted many of tour posts to try to cover their other fraudulent activity. In any case, you weren’t “robbed”. By no fault of your own you had been the target of fraudulent votes. Those have been corrected. The identity of the culprits is generally kept hidden, logically. Nobody likes a witch-hunt.

Comment: @10Rep: I'm happy helping people, specially newbies.You can check my answers (45 thus far), I always try to include an example in a Code Snippet, so the OP can check (or play) with my code.

Comment: @yivi: But that's **unfair** because the majority of my reputation points were obtained by accepted answers (45 thus far, not all accepted). Did I "cheat" on that too? As I said in my post. I don't have anything to hide. Anybody can see my recent activity.

Comment: Read again; I didn’t accuse you of cheating. Someone else cheated. I’m assuming you were an unwilling recipient of these fraudulent votes. What was unfair was receiving these fraudulent votes in the first place. Now that’s being corrected. Keeping those reputation points would be unfair, right? Just move on.

Comment: @yivi: What votes are you talking about? **None** of my answers have more than **2 upvotes**. And honestly I care more about loosing points of my accepted answers. Oh, by the way, before the August 17th incident, I already had 400+ reputation points.

Comment: Related: *[Nicely discouraging serial upvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49651/nicely-discouraging-serial-upvoting)*

Comment: Regarding your edit: SE staff didn't return anything, you got [4 accept votes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7471180/sagnalrac?tab=reputation)   and if you really want to "audit" your reputation visit https://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: In this case, you were the victim of a serial-upvoting case. It's just unfortunate, but **serial-upvoting (voting based on the user, not the post's quality) is wrong**. You yourself were not wrong. **The upvoters were wrong** and their behavior has been corrected by reverting the upvotes which you shouldn't get in the first place.

Comment: I'm not sure what will or won't come of the 60 rep you just received. If SO reverted the "accepts", and that user just added all 4 of them again, I have no idea if that is still fraudulent or not. I'm thinking *no*, since there's no way to stop a user from accepting any answer on their own question, but it's still odd. Like @rene said, there was no rep "returned" to you, this was new rep from the same source.

Answer (score 20):

> I got a message from several moderators asking me about this suspicious activity. I explained to them the same I just said. And they decided to subtract me 210 reputation points (as you can see in the picture I'm including in this post). I didn't complain because I thought it was fair, and besides, I don't want to have any problems with this community.

The 210 reputation points was dropped automatically. Post this, we escalated it to the staff, who have *actual* tools to investigate cross voting on users. The CMs [had 600 such requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353982/311398) in their backlog and cleared this ticket yesterday, where they found an additional 190 reputation points exchanged, which was also removed.

If you have concerns/issues about this, the right place to air them would be to send a message directly to the Stack Exchange staff, by using the contact page. Normal meta users don't have the necessary tools/information to handle this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and your advice. I almost sure about that night I got 260 reputation points (maybe I could be wrong, but I'm very positive that they weren't 300 or above) from the same user. I didn't know about the Stack Exchange staff. I honestly thought this was the appropriate site to check that kind of situations.

Comment: To be honest, you never know who upvoted you when, so you can never say that they voted you more than 300. But yeah, the staff are the right people to discuss this with.

Comment: Believe me! That was a weird exception because he/she did that almost in front of my eyes! I mean, I literally saw one notification after another when he/she was upvoting all my answers (at that moment I only had between 19 - 26). By the way, could you explain to me how can I contact the Stack Exchange staff, please?

Comment: @Sagnalrac https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact

Answer (score 20):

I can't share who did it, but I can at least explain why this happened.

On Aug 16 you were serially upvoted

[image: seventeen times in the space of six minutes.]

The serial upvoting script caught these and reversed them on Aug 17. The problem is there were more votes cast than just this batch. In cases like this, we have to escalate to a Community Manager (Moderators cannot directly see votes cast, nor can we invalidate votes). That escalation was handled today as part of the [CM Ticket Smash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353982). A Community Manager looked at this and reversed more votes.

Comment: Finally an answer! Thank you very much for that. Although I disagree because that night I got 260 reputation points (if my memory doesn't betray me) because of that user. And now I have been subtracted 400! But I appreciate your answer very much because now at least I know what happened.

Comment: @Sagnalrac - Just check your reputation history.  It doesn’t make you we’re serially upvoted, which isn’t allowed, so the voting was corrected.  *The reputation is gone*. It wasn’t a punishment

Comment: @SecurityHound: I'm afraid I didn't understand you very well. As I already explained, the "massive upvote" by the same user was on the August 16th night (as you can see in **Machavity** picture), and mods subtracted 210 rep pts the next day (17th), as you can watch it on my picture. From that day to yesterday, I got all my rep pts. by answering questions, some upvotes (from the OP or maybe other users) and a few post edits. That was the reason for why I didn't know why I got 190 rep pts. subtracted almost one month after that incident.